# The data in my database is shown as question mark

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I've developed a desktop application using C# with a Local SQL Server 2012 database, and entered data to this database in Arabic language. Unfortunately, when I checked my database I found the data like '*??????*' as shown:

[image]

Although I set the column types  to `nvarchar`, the database collation was `SQL latin` not `Arabic`. Even when I changed the DB collation to `Arabic_CI_AS`, the previous data still appears like '*???*'.

However, my database is working well with **new entries** now, but is there any way to show **old data** that shown in above image?

Comment: Just note that you are not showing what is in the database, you are showing what the query tool (SSMS?) is able to display. This might not be the same thing. I would query the database with something you know can read a wider character set, and analyze what is really there. Or try sql functions that show what the ascii values of those columns are.

Comment: @TomC Thanks for replay, the image above is the result of sql query: `select c1, c2, c3, c4 from TableName`

Comment: Yes I understand that. But the way you are looking at the data is through a query tool which is trying to represent what is in the database. If its a character set it cant display then it will display something as placeholders for what it can display. The data actually inside the database may be your correct data, so you have to find another way to discover that. Try checking the ascii value of the first character of one of the columns, that might point you in the right direction. The collation wont help, as this is not a question of collation, comparison, or sorting, its a question of display

Comment: @TomC Thanks for advice, I have no idea about other displaying tools, therefore, I but this question here and hope to find solution. I will try to start from your advice. Thanks again Tom.